# how to create a json object in c using Jansson

Tags: c, json

I'm new to MQTT and I want to send a message using [paho c client library](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-client-library-pahocclient/), I can send the message as a char* but I need to convert it to JSON format.

I found [Jansson](https://digip.org/jansson/) from json.org to create a JSON object to send as an MQTT message.

here is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jansson.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // .....  creating client ....

    //creating JSON
    long int timestamp = 1609446771;
    float temperature = 30.14;
    float D850 = 102.48;
    float D280 = 4845.84;
    
    json_t *obj = json_pack("{s:s,s:s,s:s,s:s}",
                            "timestamp", timestamp,
                            "temperature", temperature,
                            "D850", D850,
                            "D280", D280);

    // .... publishing message ....    
}
```

I compiled the code with:

`gcc -L/home/MYUSER/MQTT/paho.mqtt.c/build/output pahocclient.c -lpaho-mqtt3c -ljansson -lm -o publish_c.out`

the code compiles with no error, but when I run it I get a segmentation fault error:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding a `NULL` last argument to `json_pack` and compile both your C code and the JANSSON librtary with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: do you mean  `json_t *obj = json_pack("{s:s,s:s,s:s,s:s}", "timestamp", timestamp, "temperature", temperature, "D850", D850, "D280", D280, NULL);` and compile with: `gcc -L/home/shahriar/MQTT/paho.mqtt.c/build/output pahocclient.c -lpaho-mqtt3c -ljansson -lm -Wall -Wextra -g -o publish_c.out` ?? I still get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error

Comment: I mostly mean that you should take more time in reading the documentation of libraries you are using

Answer (score 0):

You first need to take more time to read about the [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) format.

Then, your

```
json_t *obj = json_pack("{s:s,s:s,s:s,s:s}",
                        "timestamp", timestamp,
                        "temperature", temperature,
                        "D850", D850,
                        "D280", D280);
```

is badly typed. Since you use `s` everywhere in the first argument, you should pass C strings everywhere.

For example:

```
long int timestamp = 1609446771;
char timestampbuf [64];
memset(timestampbuf, 0, sizeof(timestampbuf));
snprintf (timestampbuf, sizeof(timestampbuf), "%ld", timestamp);
```

then pass    `"timestamp", timestampbuf,`  to `json_pack`.

Alternatively, take more time to [read the documentation of libjansson](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/2.8/apiref.html#building-values). Maybe you should change the `"{s:s,s:s,s:s,s:s}"` string and change the specification of the JSON data?

You could even consider writing your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to check at compile time the typing of most `json_pack` calls. See the [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) static analyzer.

If you compile with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), be sure to read its documentation and to run it with all warnings and debug information: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger.

You could also compile [jansson](https://digip.org/jansson/) from its source code with similar compile options (or `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -O2`)

Before coding, document in written English (or in a common human language), with [EBNF notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form), the JSON you want to send, and send that document (maybe by email) to the person writing the receiving side.